# app crashes on start on iPad but not on iPhone

Tags: ios, crash, scenekit

I have created an iPhone app using SceneKit. It works as expected on iphone. I also tried to run that same app on an iPad, but the app crashes right before `viewDidAppear` is called-`viewWillAppear` is called successfully. The error is **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** and it is shown in the `appDelegate`. I am little confused why this is happening. Have you guys ever encountered a similar problem?

EDIT: It works on ipad simulator, but not on a device.

[image]